# Parse.js onResize() with rectangle

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I'm very new to Paper.js and not that familiar with JS (be happy, these are some easy rep points!)
I want to center a rectangle in a canvas and I succeed. The problem is that I'd like that this rectangle stays in the middle when onResize is called and the doc didn't explain that very well or, at least, I didn't find something consistant.

Here is my code:

```
createYearBar(1983, 2015);

function createYearBar(yearStart, yearEnd){
    var yearsToDraw = (yearEnd - yearStart);
    var topLeftX = view.center.x * 0.2;
    var topRightX = view.center.x * 1.8;
    var barSize = topRightX - topLeftX;
    var perYear = (barSize)/yearsToDraw;
    var topleft = new Point(topLeftX, 20);
    var size = new Size(barSize, 30);
    var rect = new Rectangle(topleft, size);
    var barPath = new Path.Rectangle(rect);
    barPath.strokeColor = 'black';
    barPath.fillColor = 'black'
}
```

So it draws a rectangle like I want but it does nothing when I resize. I do not get why because this `view.center.x` should come from the framework.

It is a bit better if I add:

```
function onResize(event) {
    createYearBar(1983, 2015);
}
```

because my bar can get bigger but not smaller because it just adds bars over the already existing ones.

My question is:

**Do I need to that manually and delete and recreate the bar manually or did I miss something trivial (I assume that I missed something!)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a couple of things, but you are correct in your guess: the easiest thing to do is destroy and recreate a bar on each `resize` event.

`view.center` just returns a regular coordinate when you call it. If a view is 300x400, view.center will return a new Point object at [150, 200]. It is not a dynamic point that updates the positions of objects when you resize the window.

The problem is that you aren't removing the `barPath` object when you resize the view. It's much easier to do this if your function returns an object instead of creating one anonymously inside a function scope:

```
var barPath = createYearBar(1983, 2015);

function createYearBar(yearStart, yearEnd){
    var yearsToDraw = (yearEnd - yearStart);
    var topLeftX = view.center.x * 0.2;
    var topRightX = view.center.x * 1.8;
    var barSize = topRightX - topLeftX;
    var perYear = (barSize)/yearsToDraw;
    var topleft = new Point(topLeftX, 20);
    var size = new Size(barSize, 30);
    var rect = new Rectangle(topleft, size);
    barPath = new Path.Rectangle(rect);
    barPath.strokeColor = 'black';
    barPath.fillColor = 'black';
    return barPath;
}

function onResize(event) {
    barPath.remove();
    barPath = createYearBar(1983, 2015);
}
```